# ASP.NET MVC 4 How to edit data that comes from a foreign key

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my problem :

I have a database that contains several attributes like name etc. But I also have 2 specifics attributs, they are IISSettings and SQLSettings.

```
  public class Environment
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual SQLSettings SQL { get; set; }

    public virtual IISSettings IIS { get; set; }
...
}
```

IISSettings and SQLSettings contains both a name and an ID for foreign keys.

When I try to update a Environment, and that I only change attributs in IISSettings or SQLSettings, Visual Studio is telling me that nothing has changed, probably because in "standards" attributs, nothing has changed. The only thing that changed are the values inside IISSettings or SQLSettings.
So, I wanted to know how could I save changes to my database, when I only want to update IISSettings or SQLSettings?

My viewModel :

```
public class EnvironmentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Environment Environment { get; set; }
    public IISSettings IISSettings { get; set; }
    public SQLSettings SQLSettings { get; set; }

    //create/details/delete functions etc.

    internal void Edit()
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(Environment).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\nDbUpdateConcurrencyException : " + ex);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

ViewModelBase is where my db is set. Standard DbSet :

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    protected MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext ();
}
```

and

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
}
```

Working code :

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Environment.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Environment.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Environment.Name)
</div>
```

Not working code :

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Environment.IIS.IISServer)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Environment.IIS.IISServer)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Environment.IIS.IISServer)
</div>
```

It's when I try to save the changes into my database and that I only change the name of an SQLSettings that I get an error. A DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

Any suggestions? 
(if I forgot something please tell me) :)

Comment: Perhaps the contents of the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and its properties can come in handy in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it.
Just needed to add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Environment.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Environment.IIS.IISSettingsID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Environment.SQL.SQLSettingsID)
```

to my edit View.
And this to my Edit() method inside EnvironmentController :

```
db.Environments.Attach(Environment);
db.Entry(Environment).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(Environment.IIS).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(Environment.SQL).State = EntityState.Modified;
```